# Getting back item picked up by guard NPC while having a bounty in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When visiting Whiterun, I accidentally dropped Hevnoraak's staff which was picked up by Commander Caius. I had a high bounty from killing soldiers, so the guards attacked me when fast travelling to Whiterun.

I cannot kill him as he is essential, and I don't know how to use game codes.

How can I get my staff back?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming SE. I proposed an edit to make your question a bit more readable. If I misinterpreted your original post, feel free to make further edits to clarify.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are playing on PC or console? On PC code might be your easiest fix. Someone will be able to post an answer on how to do this, quite easily.

Comment: I didn't even know NPCs pick up objects o_O

Comment: @Ciacciu Not very often, but they may pick up objects you drop and return them to you. [See this uesp list](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions#Reactions)

Comment: Have you tried picking his pocket?  If he's choosen to wield it you can steal it from him with the correct perk in the pick pocket tree

Answer (score 2):

There are only so many options available:

- Pickpocket
- Use game console to spawn another staff
- Use game console to kill NPC (not recommended)

If you're interested in the staff for its usefulness, it actually isn't a very useful staff :)